# Module not found:Error:Can't resolve 'vue'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-mix

I am trying to create simple CRUD with laravel and vuejs. When i run '`npm run watch`' it says
[npm run watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LBzb.png)

And, when I run `php artisan serve`, it shows nothing with no error

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYh4o.png)

Here is my code
[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKquv.png)

[app.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9tjJ.png)

Comment: Please post the code and not screenshots to the code. There is a built in code snippet thingy and you can use backticks to denote a code block

Answer (score 15):

In `webpack.mix.js`, just put a `.vue()` like this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]).vue();
```

Comment: This is the only thing that helped me. I've been looking for a solution for 2 days.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are missing the import statement, so it can not resolve `Vue`. Add this at the top of your `app.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Comment: @lazymouse then you need to update your question, to give us more info.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and I resolved it by copying the configuration from [Laravel Jetstream](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/tree/afe570ccf1c65d177d812c4d4a8c1ad1c495b2ac/stubs/inertia):

```js
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
        },
    },
};
```

```js
// webpack.mix.js 

const mix = require('laravel-mix')

mix
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .vue()
  .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    // prettier-ignore
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
  ])
  .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'))
  .sourceMaps()
;

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```